# IBM Worklight Android's checkbox always disabled while adding new environment

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I successfully installed IBM Worklight and Android plug-in in a fresh new Eclipse, however this is what I get when I want to create new Worklight Environment - the Android checkbox is always disabled, so I cannot create a new environment.

[image]

In case you need it, this is my Android SDK version:

[image]

I have tried to search this issue but I still can't solve it.
Theres no error or warning, everything seems fine.

**Additional note :** I have 2 eclipse installations that use the same Android SDK, but I think it has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the first screenshot, you did not create a Worklight project (and application). You cannot create an environment if no Worklight project and application exist.

1. Create a new Worklight project
2. Create a new Worklight application
3. Add an environment to your application

In your Eclipse toolbar click on the Worklight icon and choose to create a Worklight project and follow the steps above, provided by the wizard.

May I suggest to also go over the [IBM Worklight Getting Started training materials](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/), which will teach you how to use Worklight. From setting up the development environment,  creating new projects, to adding simple and advanced features, utilizing adapters and so on.

*quote:*

> **Additional note:** I have 2 eclipse installations that use the same
>   Android SDK, but I think it has nothing to do with this.

That's correct. At this stage, ADT is not yet required. ADT is required only once you're ready to deploy your application to an Android emulator/device.